# Однокоренные слова

Tags: этимология

*Слон, слоняться, прислоняться* - однокоренные ли это слова и, если да, то при чем тут слон?

Comment: [Похожая](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/27437/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F) тема уже обсуждалась, но без слона.

Comment: user244413, на даты обращайте внимание и на ники авторов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, слон аболютно ни при чем.
"Слоняться", "прислониться", видимо, восходят к "клониться", отсюда же заслон, образования старые, явно древнее слона.

Сам же слон, видимо, окказиональное образование с не совсем ясной этимологией, возможно связано с тюркским aslan - лев. Первоначально означало крупное животное вообще.

Версии о происхожнеии "слоняться" от "выгуливать слона" неубедительны, как и обратное - слон от "спит прислонившись".

Answer (score 0):

Хочу поддержать смелые, действительно революционные исследования энтузиастов сфере этимологии. Слово вполне может оказаться артефактом сродни археологическому. Большинство этимологов слабы тем, что они не знают ни одного языка толком (даже родного). Я внимательно прочитал труды Фоменко по Новой хронологии. С точки зрения математики мне как историку крыть нечем. Я могу лишь эмоционально возмущаться некоторыми предположениями. Но что делать, если они приводят карты звёздного неба, расчёты положений светил? Разве я могу этому хоть что-то противопоставить? То же самое с "Новой этимологией" коллеги Славянинова. Тов.Бегемот (а также некий СИТБЛ) ни слова не знает на финском, эстонском, прочих финно-угорских. Ну как вы можете так неприлично спорить? Спорить могут знающие люди. А незнающие должны думать!

Comment: Накипело... А по сути Вопроса, не переходя на личности, есть что сказать?

Comment: А я внимательно прочитал Вас. До слова "Фоменко". Дальше не стал.

Answer (score -1):

Насчёт этимологии слова "слон" у меня есть личная догадка. Если верить Википедии, в XVII-XIIX веках был такой британский коллекционер [Hans Sloane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Sloane). В его коллекцию как-то попал экземпляр бивня [мамонта](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammoth), добытый в Сибири. Но поскольку существование мамонтов ещё не было доказано, он публично заявлял что бивень является слоновьим. Может быть, слово "слон" пошло от его фамилии?

Comment: Каким образом фамилия некоего британца могла породить слово, известное задолго до того?

Comment: Слово-то может и известно было, вопрос в том с какого времени им стали называть это самое животное? Если доподлинно известно что слона называли слоном задолго до этого британца, то мое предположение неверно.

Comment: Ваше предположение неверно в любом случае. Слово фиксируется с незапамятной древноности, *Происходит от праслав. *slonъ, от кот. в числе прочего произошли: др.-русск. слонъ (Афан. Ник., библия 1499 г.),...* (Фасмер), какие еще, к черту, англичане с мамонтами?

Comment: Так я и спрашиваю, что именно означали слова "slonъ" и древне-русское "слонъ" в те времена?

Comment: Я не жил в те времена. И англичанин ваш тоже не жил. Это понятно, надеюсь?

Comment: Да. И раз вы не знаете ответа на этот вопрос, то и опровергнуть мое предположение вы не сможете. Слова могут быть созвучны (или даже одинаковы), но никак не связаны по смыслу и иметь разную этимологию. Такое бывает.

Comment: А я и не собираюсь опровергать. )))