# Слоняться и ПРИслоняться

Tags: словообразование, однокоренные-слова

"Слоняться" — ходить без определенной цели, "прислоняться" — прижиматься, облокачиваться. Слова отличаются только приставкой, а значения совершенно разные. Интересно, почему так?
Прошу прощения, если вопрос глупый

Comment: Вообще-то очень похоже на повтор вопроса.

http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/2345/

Пускай модератор решает.

Если не сочтет так, то я свой ответ оттуда перенесу.
*Интересно, почему тогда ни у кого возражений не вызвало?
Даже у Груманта )))*

Comment: А может в слове *при-с-лон-ять-ся* две приставки? А корень -- *лон*.

Comment: Вопрос не глупый, но повтор. И ещё, что важно, «прислоняться» никак не значит «прижиматься, облокачиваться», а опираться телом (частью тела) для устойчивости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово слоняться - жаргонное. Оно появилось в Санкт-Петербурге после прибытия персидского посольства, которое привезло с собой подарок - слона. Было это в 1717 году. Слон жил недолго - около 3-х лет. При Анне Иоановне из Индии завезли новых слонов.
Так вот, зоопарка не было, и слона выводили гулять по улицам города. Слон, здоровенное сильное животное, которое можно было бы использовать эффективнее, чем лошадь, ходил без дела - слонялся. Так родилось новое слово.
Слово "слон" является этимоном по отношению к слову "слоняться".
Именно эта тема легла в основу басни Крылова "Слон и Моська".

Comment: Совершенно верно! Было даже выражение специальное : **слоны слонять**.  
> В. В. Крестовский. **Петербургские трущобы**. Книга о сытых и голодных. Роман в шести частях. Ч. 5. (1867) ― Ты бы хошь грешное тело чем-нибудь прикрыл, свинья ты эдакая, нечем **промеж людей так-то слоны слонять!**

Comment: Цитата у груманта как всегда - не по делу. 
Нельзя же серьезно воспринимать игру слов как этимологию.

Comment: Опровергать версию надо квалифицированно. Я сам могу себя поправить, но лучше, чтобы это сделал благожелательный оппонент, с двух-трех сторон контрдоводы приведя. Прошу дать объяснение и ссылку, почему нельзя слово **слон** (зверь) считать зависимым от слова **слоняться**.

Comment: > Слон м. известное огромностью своею
животное жарких стран; слоном, или даже
слоною, зывали встарь вообще тяжелое,
неуклюжее или большое животное, которое
**слоном слоняется по лесам**, например : **Полосы**
(лука) **были булатные, а жилы слоны сохатные**
( Кирша), т. е. сохатного зверя, с рассохами
лося. Слона-то я и не заметил! Крылов . **Эка
верзила парень: слон слоном шатается**! Ученые
различают два вида: слон азиатский и
африканский, кроме допотопных, ископаемых
слонов. **Слонов продавать**, праздно шататься. (Даль)

Answer (score 3):

Попробую предложить следующее объяснение. "Слоняться" происходит от "клониться, склоняться" в ту или иную сторону, то есть незаметно и без видимой причины переходить от темы к теме, например: *Беседа началась с театра и склонилась на любовь. Разговор склонился к философии.* Возможно, "слоняться" - это как раз ходить без определенной цели, но всё же пытаясь найти хотя бы какую-то цель. Прислоняться - это тоже *присклоняться* к какому-нибудь предмету.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
А вот у Шанского написано, что сближение этого слова со "слоном" является народной этимологией. У слова "слоняться" есть родственники "склонение, клониться", все они восходят к греческому "klino" - прислоняю.

Comment: Возможно, слово "слон" известно славянам ещё с времён пребывания на территории Индии. Тогда термин "заслониться" первоначально означал "спрятаться за слона". Вообще, все слова с корнем "слон" несут в себе положительную окраску. Лишь слово "слоняться" по меньшей мере звучит иронично.

Answer (score 1):

Копирую свой ответ с аналогичного вопроса.
//--------------------
[Однокоренные слова](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2345/)
//--------------------

Думаю, слон аболютно ни при чем. "Слоняться", "прислониться", видимо, восходят к "клониться", отсюда же заслон, образования старые, явно древнее слона.

Сам же слон, видимо, окказиональное образование с не совсем ясной этимологией, возможно связано с тюркским aslan - лев. Первоначально означало крупное животное вообще.

Версии о происхожнеии "слоняться" от "выгуливать слона" неубедительны, как и обратное - слон от "спит прислонившись".

//--------------------

Удалил то, что давно потеряло актуальность.

Answer (score -2):

В былые времена люди считали, что слон спит стоя, облокотившись обо что-нибудь, и у него не сгибались колени. От этого и взялось слово "прислонившись".

Comment: Начинаю думать, что это заразно.)))

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?